# Is there a way to do a multi-item carousel with react-bootstrap?

Tags: reactjs, carousel, react-bootstrap

I've been trying to do a multi-item carousel with the react-bootstrap package and I succeded making just a single-item carousel. I am using the Instagram API to fetch some photos and the idea is to display a few of them, not just one.

I used the example I found in React docs of using a controlled component to render my images. I tried setting selectedIndex in handleSelect function to a default value of 3, which didn't work.
From what I understand activeIndex controls the visible slide so... I don't know what I am missing. 
This is the link: 
https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/carousel/

Below is some code of my controlled carousel component:

```
import Carousel from 'react-bootstrap/Carousel'

export default class ControlledCarousel extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    // this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      index: 0,
      direction: null,
    };
  }

  handleSelect = (selectedIndex, e) => {
    this.setState({
      index: selectedIndex,
      direction: e.direction,
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { index, direction } = this.state;

    return (
      <Carousel
        activeIndex={index}

        direction={direction}
        onSelect={this.handleSelect}

      >

              {this.props.images.map((image) => {
                return <Carousel.Item key={image.id}>
                  <img className="d-block w-100" alt={image.tags[0]} src={image.images.standard_resolution.url} />
                </Carousel.Item>
              })}

      </Carousel>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is fairly different from what the standard bootstrap carousels do, so not really. However, you can use different npm libraries for this!